# Install LibRaw from Github-Repo in Windows

Tags: c++, windows

I have written an application, that utilizes a very recent feature from LibRaw (namely the conversion of .CR3-images) in Linux. That's why i need to use [the LibRaw-version, that's published in their Github](https://github.com/LibRaw/LibRaw/) and not one of the official distribution-packages. Now i have to use another library, that is only available for Windows and i have to port the application to Windows.

Now, [the LibRaw-site states](https://www.libraw.org/docs/Install-LibRaw.html):

> Building under Windows has three steps:
>
> - Unpack the distribution package (if you have got no tar+gzip, take the LibRaw distribution package in the .ZIP format) and go to folder LibRaw-X.YYY.
> - Set the environment parameters so that the compiler/linker would find the libraries and include-files. For Visual C++, this is done by
>     running `vcvars32.bat`.
> - Run `nmake -f Makefile.msvc`

My problem is, that i can't find the file `vcvars32.bat`. Neither in the official distribution-package, nor anywhere in the repository.

Has anyone managed to build Github-LibRaw natively on Windows? How can i approach this problem?

Comment: `vcvars32.bat` (or in general `vcvars.bat`) ships with Visual Studio. You can either install the full IDE or just the build tools.

Comment: Yes, that worked thank you! I simply didn't know about `vcvars.bat` and assumed it was shipped with LibRaw!